# CharCreature in manim videos

Tags: python, video, manim

I want to create informative mathematics videos using the Manim engine and I would like to put some of these CharCreatures in `3Blue1Brown` videos to have more animation in.

This is what a CharCreature looks like

[Omega Creature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm5r4.png)

Do someone know how to do it and animate it?...I would like to make similar with other characters

Thanks for responding

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into this recent video from *Theorem of Beethoven*
[CharCreature: Like 3b1b NumberCreature but easy](https://youtu.be/48urQv_UD-8)